# How to execute a shell command in Pod B from Pod A using Kubertenes client in GKE

Tags: c#, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have a server deployment with Horizontal scaling. The deployment will have 3-5 pods at any given time based on the load.
I use volume mapping to pass configuration data to the deployed server pods. I have to call a reload function in my server app for it to work with the updated configuration without restarting the pod.

I use a separate .net web API app to change the config file in volume mapping (as it gets updated often).
I am trying to use the Kubernetes client to list all my application pods and then execute a refresh command.
I got an error with the refresh command, so I checked with the "ls" command but got the same issue.

I have also provided the account with rbac permissions to list the pods and execute in the pods.

Below are the permission rules I added.

```
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

Here is the sample code.

```
 V1PodList list = _client.CoreV1.ListNamespacedPod("development", labelSelector:app=MyAppSelector");
 foreach (V1Pod item in list.Items)
 {
    var webSocket = await client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync(item.Metadata.Name, "default", "ls",
        item.Spec.Containers[0].Name).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var demux = new StreamDemuxer(webSocket);
    demux.Start();
    var buff = new byte[4096];
    var stream = demux.GetStream(1, 1);
    var read = stream.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buff);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Below issue occurs at the line "var webSocket = await client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync"

`Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The server returned status code '403' when status code '101' was expected.`

I want the client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync method to execute the reload command in my sever pods.

Can you help me regarding this or guide me if I am doing anything wrong?
Also suggest me if any other alternatie approaches are available for this scenario.

Comment: Can you put the data into a ConfigMap or a similar object, and then change a hash in the Deployment spec (usually an annotation in the Pod spec template) to force the deployment to recreate its Pods?  Or can you advertise the change using some sort of messaging system?  Both the shared-volume approach and the need to use the exec API seem like they'll be hard to manage in practice.

Comment: I don't want my pods to recreate, If I recreate all my pods, the the active connections to the server will be dropped. I have a method in the server, that will refresh the server with the latest configuration without disconnecting existing connections. I am trying to call that method

Answer (score 1):

If you update a configmap which is mounted as a volume in a pod, then within a minute or two, that change is reflected within the pod's file system.

Can you not have a background thread in the application that watches for a change in the mounted configuration that will then call the reload method when it sees a change? Then you don't need to mess around with another utility that has to connect to all instances of the service and call a reload endpoint.